# taskscheduleR ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: r, r-taskscheduler

I tried to add a task scheduler from `taskscheduleR` on rstudio but it gives this error;

> Warning: running command 'schtasks /Delete /TN "script1.R" /F' had status 1
>   Creating task schedule: schtasks /Create /TN "script1.R" /TR "cmd /c C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~3/srv~1/R_SERVER/bin/Rscript.exe \"C:/Users/user1/Desktop/script1.R\"  >> \"C:/Users/user1/Desktop/script1.log\" 2>&1" /SC ONCE /ST 23:40

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the locale settings. I faced same issue and I used the task scheduler to set up a job for the future date (01-01-2020). The job set successfully. Then I went to Windows Task Scheduler and adapted the starting date to be as I wanted (e.g. 19-09-2019).